# React native giving warning when trying to post request

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When trying to perform post request with apisauce, you are giving this warning and do not make the request. What can it be?

```html
const api = create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
  
});



api.addResponseTransform(response => {
  if (!response.ok) throw response;
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPd2w.jpg)

Comment: I am not familiar with this library but probably you have to manage the possible exception of addResponseTransform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost doesn't work. You need to replace it with your IP adress.